# passing file to docker command

Tags: python, opencv, docker

I am attempting to run opencv through docker container. I have built the image and while running the container directly

`docker run -v /home/ganaraj/nndetect:/detect -ti opecv3 bash`

and accessing the bash

`$>cd /detect/prediction
 $>prediction 1.jpg
 0`

I do get the output I am expecting ( the final 0 ).

But I would actually wish to run this as a command line program.

I have tried both

`docker run -v /home/ganaraj/nndetect:/detect -ti opecv3 /detect/prediction/prediction 1.png`

`docker run -v /home/ganaraj/nndetect:/detect -ti opecv3 /detect/prediction/prediction /detect/prediction/1.png`

But both of these dont provide me the output I am expecting from this.

What would be the right way to do this, so that I can run this app easily like a command line tool ( through docker ) and get the output back ?

I have also tried

`docker run -v /home/ganaraj/nndetect:/detect -it -d opecv3 bin/bash`

and then :

`docker exec -it 3d618d63316c /detect/prediction/prediction /detect/prediction/1.png`

but still I get the same blank response.

```
Client:
 Version:      1.8.3
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   f4bf5c7
 Built:        Mon Oct 12 05:37:18 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.3
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   f4bf5c7
 Built:        Mon Oct 12 05:37:18 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: why `./detect/prediction/prediction`? Why not `/detect/prediction/prediction`

Comment: Sorry. I have used it as `/detect` later on.. But since I copy pasted from my history - I pasted the older version here.. Changing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docker exec is [mainly for debugging purpose](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9299#issuecomment-64177898).

> The primary use case of `docker exec` is debugging running containers,
>   `docker exec` basically is for "exceptional" cases

When you want to execute a command (here a python program), it is best to run a container just for that command.

```
alias dr='docker run -v /home/ganaraj/nndetect:/detect -w /detect/prediction -it --rm opecv3'
```

That way, without having python installed on your host, you could use `determined_rosalind` simply by typing:

```
dr ./prediction 1.png
```

That would launch a *[transient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_%28computer_programming%29)* container to run the python program, exit and be removed (`--rm` option).

Comment: I was thinking about this.. But just did not know the exact way to achieve this.. I am new to docker and I initially started quite a few instances of docker , by running docker run a few times.. the --rm option solves all this.. This is the most intuitive way to run this.. ty.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it working - but I am not sure "why" this makes it work.. If someone has an explanation for why please add it too..

But I thought it might be a good idea to post the final solution here..

I started the container with the following command :

`docker run -v /home/ganaraj/nndetect:/detect -w /detect/prediction -it -d opecv3 bash`

And now I can make the prediction with this command and it works fine

`docker exec -it determined_rosalind ./prediction 1.png`